# Drop down in html using php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying populate a list into a drop down menu, currently it is displaying like this:

[image: http://i.gyazo.com/874064aba8f31d5f2213596769e10fb1.png]

Where each name is in its own drop down, but I am trying to put all the names into just one drop down instead - how could I do this?

Also could the echo statements be in a better format for this. I saw the echo using double quotes on other questions but had to use single to work. Thanks

```
<?php


require_once 'db/connect.php';




    // Query to display students in the tutor logged in
    if ($result = $con->query("SELECT Student.Form, Teacher.Form, Student.Forename, Student.Surname " .
                                "FROM Student, Teacher " .
                                    "WHERE Student.Form = Teacher.Form AND Teacher.Form = 'C'")) {
        if ($result->num_rows) {
            $count= $result->num_rows;
            if ($count > 0) {
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    //echo $row['Forename'] . ' ' . $row['Surname'] .  ' <br> ' ;
                    echo '<select>';
                    echo '<option value = "students"> ' . $row['Forename'] . ' ' . $row['Surname'] . '</option>';                   
                    echo '</select>';
                    }
                }
        }           
    }

?>
```

Comment: Simple, take your select tags out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
<?php

require_once 'db/connect.php';

// Query to display students in the tutor logged in
if ($result = $con->query("SELECT Student.Form, Teacher.Form, Student.Forename, Student.Surname " .
                            "FROM Student, Teacher " .
                                "WHERE Student.Form = Teacher.Form AND Teacher.Form = 'C'")) {
    if ($result->num_rows) {
        $count= $result->num_rows;
        if ($count > 0) {
                echo '<select>';
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                //echo $row['Forename'] . ' ' . $row['Surname'] .  ' <br> ' ;

                echo '<option value = "students"> ' . $row['Forename'] . ' ' . $row['Surname'] . '</option>';                   

                }
                echo '</select>';
            }
    }           
}

?>
```

Just take out the "select" tag from the while. :P

Comment: You can also skip `if($count > 0)` - this is exactly the same as `if($result->num_rows)`

Comment: and maybe, should add another value for each option, so it could be used elsewhere.

Comment: @msfoster so that line is completely not needed? thanks

Comment: @pojomx can you expand on what you mean and an example? appreciated

Comment: I posted the code, the while makes you put a lot of "select" elements (Dropdown elements) for each of your rows in the database, then, if you have a value "students" for each of your students, when you select one, it  always be "students" and not George Turner, for example.  

echo '<option value = "{$row['_id']}"> ' . $row['Forename'] . ' ' . $row['Surname'] . '</option>';

Comment: @pojomx  ok i think I understand you - so I should set the option value to the unique identifier in the database, in my case its called "Student_ID" in the student table

Comment: Yup, that way the system can know WHO you selected :P

Comment: @pojomx  ok will do, just tried to add it and the format must be wrong, error is: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Student_ID' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'  when i tried the following: '<option value = "{$row['Student_ID']}">' simple syntax error?

Comment: sorry, my mistake. 

"<option value =\"". $row['Student_ID'] ."\">"